# RecyclerView with CardView is lagging on scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, lag

i am using recyclweview in fragment having CardView in items  but when i scrolling is lagging too much,  i have seen many solution but i can not find solution, if any one can help me then here is my code bellow , thanks you

Fragment:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_venues_clubs, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        thisActivity = getActivity();
        TAG = "VenuesClubsFragment";

        user_id = Utils.getUserId(thisActivity);
        latitude = SharedPreferenceHelper.getLocationData(thisActivity, SharedPreferenceHelper.LATITUDE);
        longitude = SharedPreferenceHelper.getLocationData(thisActivity, SharedPreferenceHelper.LONGITUDE);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(thisActivity) {
            @Override
            protected int getExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state) {
                return 300;
            }
        };

        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rvClubList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                venuesClubsBarsResponse = null;
                refreshData(false, false);
            }
        });

        btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                venuesClubsBarsResponse = null;
                refreshData(false, false);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

setAdapterMethod:

```
     private void setUpRecylerViewData() {
        LogUtils.i(TAG, "size " + venuesClubsBarsResponse.getData().size());

        venuesAdapter = new VenuesAdapter(thisActivity, new ArrayList<>(venuesClubsBarsResponse.getData())) {
            @Override
            protected int getLastVisiblePosition() {
                return linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            }

            @Override
            protected void refreshItems(boolean newOnce, boolean oldOnce) {
                super.refreshItems(newOnce, oldOnce);
                if (!isSearchDataAvailable) {
                    refreshData(newOnce, oldOnce);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onItemClick(int position, VenuesClubsBarsData venuesClubsBarsData) {
                super.onItemClick(position, venuesClubsBarsData);
                Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, VenueProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM_ID, venuesClubsBarsData.getId());
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM_NAME, venuesClubsBarsData.getVenueName());
                startActivity(intent);
                Utils.openActivityAnimation(thisActivity);
            }
        };

        venuesAdapter.addAll(venuesClubsBarsResponse.getData());
        rvClubList.setAdapter(venuesAdapter);
        rvClubList.addOnScrollListener(venuesAdapter.onScrollListener);
    }
```

Adapter

```
    public abstract class VenuesAdapter extends RecyclerArrayAdapter<VenuesClubsBarsData, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<VenuesClubsBarsData> venuesList;
    private Context context;
    private int lastAnimatedPosition = -1;
    public RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener;
    private boolean isFromFavourite = false;

    public VenuesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VenuesClubsBarsData> venuesClubsBarsDataArrayList) {
       init(context,venuesClubsBarsDataArrayList);
    }

    public VenuesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VenuesClubsBarsData> venuesClubsBarsDataArrayList, boolean isFromFavourite) {
        init(context,venuesClubsBarsDataArrayList);
        this.isFromFavourite = isFromFavourite;
    }


    public void init(Context context, ArrayList<VenuesClubsBarsData> venuesClubsBarsDataArrayList) {
        this.venuesList = venuesClubsBarsDataArrayList;
        this.context = context;

        onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            int previousLastVisibleItem = -1;

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if (dy > 0) {
                    int totalItem = venuesList.size();
                    int lastVisiblePosition = getLastVisiblePosition();
                    if (totalItem > 1 && previousLastVisibleItem != lastVisiblePosition) {
                        boolean refresh = (lastVisiblePosition >= (totalItem - 2));
                        if (refresh) {
//                            LogUtils.e("scroll down", "===============Scroll Down==============");
//                            LogUtils.e("last visible position", "==============" + getLastVisiblePosition());

                            refreshItems(false, true);
                        }
                        previousLastVisibleItem = lastVisiblePosition;
//                        LogUtils.e("previous last visible position", "==============" + previousLastVisibleItem);
                    }

                }
            }
        };
    }

    protected abstract int getLastVisiblePosition();

    protected void refreshItems(boolean newOnce, boolean oldOnce) {
    }

    protected void onItemClick(int position, VenuesClubsBarsData venuesClubsBarsData) {
    }

    public void addVenues(VenuesClubsBarsData venuesClubsBarsData) {

        int lastPosition = venuesList.size() - 1;
        venuesList.add(venuesList.size(), venuesClubsBarsData);
        this.add(lastPosition, venuesClubsBarsData);
        notifyItemInserted(lastPosition);
    }

    public void updateAll(List<VenuesClubsBarsData> clubsBarsDataList) {
        if (venuesList != null) {
            venuesList.clear();
        }
        this.clear();
        venuesList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.addAll(clubsBarsDataList);
        venuesList.addAll(clubsBarsDataList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_venues_clubs_bars_list, parent, false);
        return new CellFeedViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        CellFeedViewHolder holder = (CellFeedViewHolder) viewHolder;
        VenuesClubsBarsData venuesClubsBarsData = venuesList.get(position);
        holder.bindData(position, venuesClubsBarsData, isFromFavourite);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return venuesList.size();
    }

    public class CellFeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.iv_venue_featured_pic)
        ImageView ivVenueFeaturedPic;
        @Bind(R.id.iv_overlay_image)
        ImageView ivOverlayImage;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_rating)
        CustomFontTextView tvRating;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_venue_name)
        CustomFontTextView tvVenueName;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_followers)
        CustomFontTextView tvFollowers;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_city_country)
        CustomFontTextView tvCityCountry;
        @Bind(R.id.linear_view)
        LinearLayout linearView;
        @Bind(R.id.iv_verified)
        ImageView ivVerified;
        @Bind(R.id.iv_icon)
        ImageView ivIcon;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_distance)
        CustomFontTextView tvDistance;
        @Bind(R.id.cv_club_bar)
        CardView cvClubBar;
        int position;
        VenuesClubsBarsData venuesClubsBarsData;

        public CellFeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            cvClubBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemClick(position, venuesClubsBarsData);
                }
            });
        }

        public void bindData(int position, VenuesClubsBarsData venuesClubsBarsData, boolean isFromFavourite) {
            this.position = position;
            this.venuesClubsBarsData = venuesClubsBarsData;

            tvVenueName.setText(venuesClubsBarsData.getVenueName());
            tvRating.setText(venuesClubsBarsData.getRating());
            tvFollowers.setText(venuesClubsBarsData.getFollowers() + " followers");
            tvCityCountry.setText(venuesClubsBarsData.getCity() + ", " + venuesClubsBarsData.getCountry());
            tvDistance.setText(venuesClubsBarsData.getDistance() + " mi");
            ivVerified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            if (venuesClubsBarsData.isVerified()) {
//                ivVerified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            } else {
//                ivVerified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            }

            if (isFromFavourite){
                ivIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (venuesClubsBarsData.getIsThisClub()){
                    ivIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.club_icon);
                }else if (venuesClubsBarsData.getIsThisBar()){
                    ivIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bar_icon);
                }
            }else {
                ivIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (StringUtils.isValid(venuesClubsBarsData.getVenueFeaturedPic())) {
                try {
                    String imgUrl = venuesClubsBarsData.getVenueFeaturedPic();
                    Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl).placeholder(R.mipmap.logo).into(ivVenueFeaturedPic);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                ivVenueFeaturedPic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.logo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv_club_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:clickable="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Venues_club_imageview_height"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back_ground">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_venue_featured_pic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:src="@mipmap/logo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_overlay_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/overlay_screen"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <whatsfourtwonite.quriousclick.com.whats42nite.widget.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_rating"
                    style="@style/text_view_showing_distance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
                    android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@mipmap/star"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:paddingRight="6dp"
                    tools:text="5.0" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp">

                <whatsfourtwonite.quriousclick.com.whats42nite.widget.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_venue_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                    android:shadowDx="3"
                    android:shadowDy="3"
                    android:shadowRadius="5"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="Venue Name" />


                <whatsfourtwonite.quriousclick.com.whats42nite.widget.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_followers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    tools:text="2 followers" />

                <whatsfourtwonite.quriousclick.com.whats42nite.widget.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_city_country"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="City, Country" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/iv_verified"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:src="@mipmap/progress_sm_w03" />

                <whatsfourtwonite.quriousclick.com.whats42nite.widget.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
                    style="@style/text_view_showing_distance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_near_me_white_18dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    tools:text="11.25 mi" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:src="@mipmap/bar_icon"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not thee problem of CardView. What is the resolution of images that you are 
using in for ImageView in the layout for RecyclerView.

1. If you are using high quality images that are in drawable/, then move those images to drawable-hdpi or drawable-xhdpi.

2.If the images are from remote server, try to get images of appropriate resolution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  1. No i am not using any images. 
2. I tried removing the imageview and load only the blanck cardview, however still the issue persist.

Comment: What about backgrounds.  android:background="@drawable/overlay_screen", Hope you removed it too.

Comment: yes, i also tried android:background="@drawable/overlay_screen", removing once